# Dúvida sobre versão de dll

Tags: c#, .net

Eu estou com um problema com as minhas dlls
Umas telas é a "System.ValueTuple.dll"

O meu packages.config está com a versão **4.5.0**.

Mas quando o projeto é compilado, ele gera a dll com a versão **4.6.26515.6**

E no meu app.config, tem o seguinte:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.0" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

E em algumas máquinas (nem todas) ocorre o seguinte erro:

> "Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assemply 'System.ValueTuple,
>   Version=**4.0.33.0**, Culture=neutra,
>   PulicKeyToken=cc7bf13ffcd2ddd51'"

São 4 lugares ontem tem a versão dessa dll e todas estão diferentes.
E já tentei colocar tudo igual e não estou conseguindo resolver esse erro.

Comment: Caso seu projeto use `AssemblyInfo.cs` procure pela linha`AssemblyVersion` e veja se  tem asteriscos(*). Os asteriscos significam incrementação automática de valor.

Comment: Não tem (*) no AssemblyVersion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz do Downgrade da "System.ValueTuple.dll" para versão "4.4.0" e resolveu o problema.

---

**Atualização**

Na verdade a alteração da versão não resolveu o problema. 
Eu tive que excluir o arquivi `System.Net.Http.dll` da pasta do visual studio
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570912/strange-issue-with-system-net-http-4-2-0-0-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite Gustavo.

Provavelmente sua solução tem mais de um projeto e o que pode estar ocorrendo é que há versões diferentes dos pacotes instaladas nos projetos.

No Visual Studio (versões recentes), clicando com o botão direito na Solução, você pode acessar o Gerenciador de Pacotes do NuGet para a Solução. Na tela de gerenciamento vai aparecer uma aba consolidar que irá apontar quais os pacotes tem diferentes versões na solução.

Por lá mesmo você poderá CONSOLIDAR os pacotes para a versão que achar mais adequada.